# Heavy I/O and python multiprocessing/multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I am designing a little soft which involves:

1. Fetching a resource on the internet,
2. Some user interaction (quick editing of the resource),
3. Some processing.

I would like to do so with many resources (they are all listed in a list). Each is independent from the others. Since the editing part is quite weary, I would like to make life easier for the user (probably me) so that he does not have to wait for the download of each ressource. For simplicity we forget the third task here.

My idea was to use the threading or multiprocessing module. Some thread (say thread 1) would do the "download" in advance while another (say thread 2) one would interact with the user on an already downloaded resource.

Question: How can I make sure that thread 1 is always ahead of at least ahead_min resources and at most ahead_max (ahead_max>ahead_min) at all times?

I typically would need something similar to Queue.Queue(ahead_max) (or multiprocessing.Queue(ahead_max)) except that when ahead_max is attained then insertion is blocked until there are at most ahead_min elements left in the queue (in fact it blocks until the queue is empty, see http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue). Popping should also be blocked until at least ahead_min+1 elements are in the queue (at the end of the sequence of resources I can then insert some dummy objects to ensure even the last resource is processed).

Any idea? If you think of any simpler alternative, please share!

Comment: In python 3 please for easy unicode support

Comment: What is the benefit of making ahead_min larger than zero?

Comment: To be sure that the user never waits. ahead_min doesn't have to be large, 2 (or maybe even 1) should be enough and give me peace of mind.

Comment: No, it would be the other way round. He has to wait until there are at least `ahead_min` items in the queue. I think a simple Queue (threading implementation) would be exactly what you need.

Comment: It downloads the next resource as soon as one is polled from the queue, so while the user is editing the next one is already downloading. Still don't see the problem...

Comment: from http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/queue.html queue.put (with block=false) will be blocked "until a free slot is available". This is indeed what I need. I do not know where I read that it would wait for the queue to be empty, maybe it's just getting too hot near the computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would suggest to subclass `Queue` and implement your own logic. This should be an easy task as the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.2.3/Lib/queue.py) of the `Queue` class is already in Python.

You can use this as template

```
from queue import Queue

class MyQueue(Queue):

    def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        ...

    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems that `threading` is preferable over `multiprocessing` in this case, because your task seems to be more IO bound than CPU bound. Then, yes, make use of queues in order to set up the communication between the different "modules". If the default `pop` behavior is not enough for you, you can play with `Queue.qsize()` and implement your own logic.